# php array operations

Tags: php, arrays, max, extract

I have the following 2D array and I would like to compare some values. First I would like to get the highest value from the array and depends on time extract from the previous value with the same index.

example:  highest(work_something(223))-previous(work_something(120))

```
$data = array(
  0 => array(
    'time' => '2011-10-03 18:43:00',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'time' => '2011-10-03 18:44:00',
  ),
  2 => array(
    'time' => '2011-10-03 18:45:00',
    'item_something' => -17,
    'keyword_something' => 0,
    'keyword_something_1' => 0,
    'search_something' => 0,
    'search_links_something' => 0,
    'work_something' => 120,
  ),
  3 => array(
    'time' => '2011-10-03 18:45:00',
    'item_something' => -17,
    'keyword_something' => 0,
    'keyword_something_1' => 0,
    'search_something' => 0,
    'search_links_something' => 0,
    'work_something' => 223,
  ),
);
```

Comment: will highest(work_something) always be the last element in the array? Meaning, if you had an element [4], would that work_something be higher than [3]['work_something']?

Comment: so far I made a loop to get maximum values in the sub arrays, than there is a problem with the time indexed value, while is interpreted as the highest. If I use unset($item['time'] than I can not compare by date and time the values. The array contains dynamical elements, so after work_something there more elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array //This is your 2D array

$highest = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value):
  if(isset($value['work_something'])){
    if($value['work_something'] > $highest){
    $highest = $value['work_something']; //This is highest 'work_something' value
    $highest_array_key = $key; //This is the key of 'work_something' array
    }
  }
endforeach;

//To compare with previews element use 
$array[$highest_array_key - 1] //this is prew element
```

**example: highest(work_something(223))-previous(work_something(120))**

```
$highest - $array[$highest_array_key - 1]['work_something'];
```